# OC4J - toplink 10/11 at same time?

Tags: jakarta-ee, oc4j, toplink

Can you use both toplink v. 10 (toplink essentials) and toplink v. 11 (eclipselink) at the same time within the OC4J application server?

Both are different implementations of JPA. I was wondering if both implementations can be added to the OC4J application server so that bean jars can choose themselves which implementation to use.

Please only real experience and knowledge, not "I think that ..." or "it should work"  or "read the manual" or "according to the spec ..." kind of answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can :-)